# Extracting first 3 out of 5 numbers through regexp in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I have following dataset:

> 781901 - Video Tape Editing
>
> 78102 - Landscape Architect

I want to be able to check for matching 781 in a 781901, and not **781** in a 78102.

How would I do this using regexp.

I have tried this query, which does not yield the result.

**select distinct sic from siccodes where sic regexp '^781';**

The caret matches at the beginning of the line, now I just need for it to disregard the 5 character codes, and only match through the 6 character ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the simplest and clearest is:

```
select distinct sic from siccodes where sic regexp '^781[0-9][0-9][0-9]';
```

Comment: This works well. But if I remove the last [0-9] the results still show the 6 character codes instead of just the 5 characters.

Comment: @user1153102: Will it always be the case that the character after the last digit is a space? If so, then you can include the space in your pattern, by writing `where sic regexp '^781[0-9][0-9] '`, to ensure that it has exactly five digits.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a integer column you could also use

```
SELECT DISTINCT sic FROM siccodes WHERE sid BETWEEN 781000 AND 781999;
```

This should be faster than the regexp.

Comment: I am storing it as a string. Because the sic code contains the text describing it.

Comment: Well, then ruakhs solution will be best. And include the space after the numbers `'^781[0-9][0-9][0-9] '` to make sure you only match 6 digits and not more.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out, it will make you fly in regex.

[Regular Expressions - Quick Reference Guid](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/)

Comment: Thank You. I will take a look at it. Anything to help me further my skills is a plus.